# Using symbols in columns with pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm using `pgfplotstabletypeset` to get datas and store them in a table.
Everything is working great.
But when I'm trying to use the symbol delta (`$\Delta$`) in the columns of my table, it doesn't work and I've no idea why.

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),$\Delta$T
43.97,0,23
44.01,0.04,32
44.04,0.07,45
44.07,0.1,86
44.11,0.14,92
44.14,0.17,100
44.17,0.2,101
44.21,0.24,102
44.24,0.27,103
44.27,0.3,115
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
 columns={Zeroed time (s),$\Delta$T},
]{test2.csv}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, I have the following warning that I dont understand (this has nothing to do with the symbol issues I'm having):
`LaTeX Warning : Writing file './test2.csv' [...]`
I understand LaTeX is writing the csv file but why this is so important to be considered as a warning ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfplotstable` handles head rows specially in a way that doesn't allow certain inputs and/or formatting.
If you change your example to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),$\Delta$ T
43.97,0,23
44.01,0.04,32
44.04,0.07,45
44.07,0.1,86
44.11,0.14,92
44.14,0.17,100
44.17,0.2,101
44.21,0.24,102
44.24,0.27,103
44.27,0.3,115
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        col sep=comma,%
        header=false,%
        string type,%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},%
        columns={1,2},%
    ]{test2.csv}
\end{document}
```

it'll work.

---

So what have I done?

- I prevented the package from interpreting each cell's content as a number by using the `string type` option. That way normal text is also allowed in cells
- I suppressed the creation of a dummy head-row (displaying the column indices) by using `every head row/.style={output empty row}`
- As there is no head row anymore the columns don't take the names specified in the first row of input data. Therefore you'll have to reference the columns by index (as you can see in the `columns={1,2}` option`).

---

If you still want all your numbers to be typeset via `\pgfmathprintnumber` you'll have to mess a little bit with the cell-content-assignment:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={%
        \normalexpandarg%
        \IfDecimal{#1}{%
            % format as number
            \pgfmathprintnumberto{#1}\result
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\result
        }{%
            % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand{#1}}%
            \fi%
        }%
    },%
}
```

When using this you can omit the `string type` option and let the alorithm decide whether to format the cell as a number or as a string. Therefore your example would look like this (Note that above code depends on the `xstring` package):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents,xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),$\Delta$ T
43.97,0,23
44.01,0.04,32
44.04,0.07,45
44.07,0.1,86
44.11,0.14,92
44.14,0.17,100
44.17,0.2,101
44.21,0.24,102
44.24,0.27,103
44.27,0.3,115
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={%
        \normalexpandarg%
        \IfDecimal{#1}{%
            % format as number
            \pgfmathprintnumberto{#1}\result
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\result
        }{%
            % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand{#1}}%
            \fi%
        }%
    },%
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        col sep=comma,%
        header=false,%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},%
        columns={1,2},%
    ]{test2.csv}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to add some over- and underlining you'll havef to make use of the `every first row` and `every last row` key (I am using the `booktabs` package to create the horizontal lines):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents,xstring, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% supress warning

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Time (s),Zeroed time (s),$\Delta$ T
43.97,0,23
44.01,0.04,32
44.04,0.07,45
44.07,0.1,86
44.11,0.14,92
44.14,0.17,100
44.17,0.2,101
44.21,0.24,102
44.24,0.27,103
44.27,0.3,115
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /pgfplots/table/assign cell content/.code={%
        \normalexpandarg%
        \IfDecimal{#1}{%
            % format as number
            \pgfmathprintnumberto{#1}\result
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\result
        }{%
            % use as String -> has to span two columns if col sep align is activated
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablepartno=0%
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand{#1}}%
            \fi%
        }%
    },%
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        col sep=comma,%
        header=false,%
        every head row/.style={output empty row},%
        columns={1,2},%
        every first row/.append style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},%
        every last row/.append style={after row=\bottomrule},%
    ]{test2.csv}
\end{document}
```

This will result in
[image: Compiled example]
You can then go ahead and change the number printing options as usual (e.g. with the `fixed` option). Even `dec sep align` should work in most cases, though there might be some issues with the "cell-content-assignment" algorithm provided above...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and energy on this. I'll finally use the first solution, easier, cleaner and enough for what I want to do for now. Thank you !